# Accessing Internal Symbols of a Package in Testing Package

Tags: testing, common-lisp

I have a program that I'd like to test using prove. Currently, I have a separate package for the tests. The problem I'm facing is that I don't really want to have to export every symbol from the primary package (I'm only exporting one currently), but I want to be able to access everything from the testing package.

Using `main-package::symbol` works, but is ugly and a bad idea I'm guessing. Is there some better way to do this without having to export all my symbols just for testing them? I've considered using the same package for writing the tests, but I don't want to have to have a `(:use :prove)` in my main package when I'm only using it for the testing code. Is there some way to do something like `(:use :package)` but only for one file? If there is, would it make sense to use that here?

Answer (score 4):

You could separate the tests into their own system. That way your main system won't have a dependency on prove at all. In the test system you can load the same source files, but different package definitions (this of course assumes you put your package definitions in a different file, rather than using the strange custom of putting them on top of your source file...).

For example, the main program might look like this:

foo.asd:

```
;; Here I'm obviously putting the package def in the same file
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage :foo-asd
  (:use :cl :asdf))
(in-package :foo-asd)

(defsystem "foo"
  :components ((:file "foo-package")
               (:file "foo")))
```

foo-package.lisp:

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage :foo
  (:use :cl)
  (:export :foo))
```

foo.lisp:

```
(in-package :foo)

(defun foo (x)
  (+ (bar x)
     (bar x)))

(defun bar (x)
  (* x x))
```

And the test system in the same directory:

foo-test.asd:

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage :foo-test-asd
  (:use :cl :asdf))
(in-package :foo-test-asd)

(defsystem "foo-test"
  :depends-on (:prove)
  :components ((:file "foo-test-package")
               (:file "foo")
               (:file "foo-test")))
```

foo-test-package.lisp

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage :foo
  (:use :cl :prove))
```

foo-test.lisp:

```
(in-package :foo)

(plan 2)
(is (bar 2)
    4)
(is (foo 2)
    8)
(finalize)
```

This lets you easily run your tests in a new image (to make sure that the version of the code that's actually on your disk works) with something like `sbcl --noinform --eval "(ql:quickload :foo-test)" --eval "(sb-ext:quit)"`. You could of course put the tests behind a function if you want.

Comment: That's an interesting method. I already had a separate system for the tests, but I hadn't thought to define an alternate version of the package that uses prove. The downside is that this requires me to replicate all the dependencies and files in the test package and test asd file as well, and any time I make a change to the main package or asd file, I'll have to make the same change in the corresponding test file.

Comment: @noctuid That's true, but I don't think there's any good way around that. I suppose you could use macros (/a feature) to conditionally add the tests and build the `defpackage`s, but that might get kinda messy. This approach has the advantage of keeping the main code is clean.

Comment: What would be the benefit of your suggestion over having a separate system that `(:depends-on :foo :prove)` and has a `(in-package :foo) (use-package :prove)` (use-package is what I was looking for) in the `foo-tests.lisp` file instead of redefining the foo package?

Comment: @noctuid That would achieve the same, except you can't make sure that there wont be name conflicts between prove and the package you're testing. If you're sure that won't be a problem, you could do that as well. I think you'll have to wrap the `use-package` in a `eval-when` though (`(eval-when (:compile-toplevel) (use-package :prove))`).